# What does the verb "nig" mean?

Tags: etymology, verbs, slang

I have seen a photo on the Internet of a customer filling a large empty jug from a soda fountain at a fast food restaurant. It had caption that someone is "gonna nig". What does "nig" mean?

Among [general reference sources](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2574/70625):

- It's not in Cambridge or OxfordDictionaries at all.
- There's no verb meaning in the Wiktionary entry.
- I couldn't view its definition in Merriam-Webster because of the paywall.
- The only verb definition in Dictionary.com lists it as a synonym for "nidge", a term used in masonry that makes no sense in context.
- "Nig" as a noun is a clipped racial slur (as seen at YourDictionary and at TheFreeDictionary, which mirrors a Wikipedia disambiguation page).

Is this related to "renege"? Or if it's a verbing of the clipped racial slur, what meaning is implied?

Comment: It's "gutter language" for assorted morons and assholes. [Here's a typical site using it](http://chimpmania.com/forum/showthread.php?52713-Niggers-gotta-Nig-in-Nig-Orleans-Nine-Shot-None-Goodified-%28Yet%29). If any of our more righteous users on ELU know how to launch a cyber-attack to take down that site and others like it, they'll have my full support. Even free speech has its limits.

Comment: Look up _niggardly_ in a dictionary: it means tight/stingy/miserly. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/niggard The verb _nig_ (to be niggardly) is not so easy to find but it does exist. That fits perfectly with the idea that someone is taking more than they should but I think it is unlikely that an obscure and obsolete 16th century verb was the intended sense.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? If you don't know what a word means, you don't know. It's a very reasonable question.

Comment: @Mitch: Admittedly, *my* downvote was partly because I find the usage being queried offensive. But it was mainly because the meaning is blindingly obvious looking at any of the first five results returned by googling "**gonna nig**", which to me means OP made no real effort to find an answer elsewhere. In fact, it now seems from OP's related meta post that he already *knew* the meaning, but apparently he wanted the meaning "documented" here on ELU. If I could, I'd vote to delete it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I totally disagree with your attitude. As long as the OP is not trolling, taboo words and their nuances, however reprehensible they are, are totally within our domain.

Comment: @Mitch: Clearly my position here is minority one. But I now see OP himself *obviously* knew the answer, since he's actually answered his own question. So I can't for the life of me see why you (and the 4 people who upvoted your first comment) think you can justify it on the grounds that some people (particularly, by implication, the querent) don't know the word. I'm all for professional dictionaries including words like "cunt", but the reasons for doing something like that are completely different. But if others want this question kept there's nothing I can do about it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If there's something about [self-answer etiquette](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) that I'm missing, feel free to explain so that I can improve the question for others who might end up here through Google.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it is my understanding that users are permitted and encouraged to answer their own questions, not a bad thing considering no one else had really attempted to. Although I do share your distaste on its use, is that a good enough reason to criticise the OP-s question?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I suppose it's possible a few of the people who use/promote this unpleasant little "slogan" are aware of the now-defunct US slang usage ***to nig** = to cheat, renege*. But since most *aren't*, and since such people are all "morons and assholes", I can't see why we would want to speculate here about what goes on in their tiny minds. Contracted ***nig** = nigger*, and subsequent "verbification of noun" are trivial features of English that could be explored without this particular example. It just looks like misguided "publicity" to me, [ab]using the ELU platform.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Defunct as I am.

Comment: @tchrist: If you say ***to nig** = to cheat, renege* is still in use in the US I can hardly argue. Since many of your fellow countrymen are unhappy about the (to me, perfectly ordinary) ***niggardly***, I took it for granted that one would have been quietly dropped decades ago. Personally, I never even knew it at all until a few days ago, and I'm hard-pressed to see how anyone could use it "innocently" today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Nig" here is a [**back-formation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation) from a word that is currently considered very offensive. It means "to behave in accord with negative stereotypes of black people."

A back-formation is a word produced by starting with a word whose form suggests a derivation but which was not produced through that derivation and then running the derivation in reverse. One might start with a word whose end looks like a suffix and chop off the suffix. For example, a "hater" is one who hates, formed from "hate" plus "-er", which means one who does something. But "lase" (to emit coherent light) and "tase" (to incapacitate with an electrical weapon) are back-formations from "laser" and "Taser", interpreting them as "lase" and "tase" plus the suffix "-er". In fact, "laser" and "Taser" are acronyms, with the "er" standing for "emission of radiation" and "electric rifle" respectively.

One might assume that "nig" is a back-formation from "renege", which according to Wiktionary can pronounced like "re-nig". "Renege" means to break a promise, and filling a jug from a self-service soda fountain certainly breaks the implied promise that the customer made to the restaurant to fill only the cup that the customer bought.

But if the photo is [the same one I found through a web search](http://www.funnyjunk.com/funny_pictures/4668293/Niggas+gonna+nig/), it says "niggers gonna nig". Here, "niggers" is an offensive term for people of sub-Saharan African descent, who are more politely called "black people". The term "nigger" ultimately comes from Latin *niger*, meaning the color black, via Spanish and Portuguese *negro*. The term originates from pre-1860s black slavery in the United States and the subsequent pre-1960s "Jim Crow" segregation laws and reflects attitudes toward black people that were prevalent in those eras.

The photo's caption appears to be a snowclone of "haters gonna hate", an idiom meaning that hostile remarks from people predisposed to such remarks are inevitable. Thus "niggers gonna nig" means two things: first, that behavior associated with negative stereotypes of black people is inevitable; and second, that black people are predisposed to such misbehavior. One such misbehavior is stealing (see sources at ["Criminal stereotype of African Americans" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criminal_stereotype_of_African_Americans)), and filling a jug when one paid for a cup might be considered stealing. In any case, in our present culture, people who assert that such a predisposition exists are called racist.

Comment: Clear and sensible.

Comment: `One such misbehavior is stealing` I think you could do with finding a source for this, else it sounds rather like your own opinion. References/attribution for your other definitions is pretty much a requirement in answers, see http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5196/71783

Comment: @Frank That page refers to direct quotations.

Comment: _Renege_ is not pronounced like ‘re-nig’ by any native speaker I’ve ever heard say the word. It is pronounced [ɹɨˈnεɪɡ], not [ɹɨˈnɪɡ] (i.e., ‘re-neyg’, not ‘re-nig’, with the same difference in vowel quality as between ‘hate’ and ‘hit’—and you wouldn’t consider “Haters gonna hit”).

Comment: I think the Chris Rock skit undermines your theory. A black man playing to a mostly black audience points out the difference between a black person and a nigger. He doesn't say 'black people steal' he says a certain type of black people steal and he labels them _niggers_ (I'm sure he's aware that other races steal too). A similar thing happens in the UK: some people (mostly Caucasian) are labelled 'spongers' or 'scroungers'; it's not racist. If he's not saying that the characteristics are determined by race itself then it's not racist, classism possibly but not racist.

Comment: @Frank Good point. Anyway, Wikipedia has an article about criminal stereotypes of black people. Are its citations any good?

Comment: Nevertheless this is a good answer, but I'm not surprised by the negative response it has received which, ironically, smacks of intolerance and prejudice.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I draw a distinction between "general reference" and "specialized reference", or between "general reference" and "application of insight combined with references". Otherwise, there'd be no justification for [self-answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Wiktionary lists [ɹɨˈnɪɡ] ("re-nig") as a pronunciation, and I've added this to the answer.

Comment: I have to say, despite some of the claims in the comments to the question, it was not at all clear to me what the verb 'nig' was supposed to mean. I googled it and saw the numerous unpleasant websites, which made it clear it's a highly derogatory term but didn't clarify the meaning for me (maybe I didn't read enough, but it got pretty sickening). But this is a good answer and made the meaning clear.

Comment: Contrary to the commentary, “Renig,” is pronounced ‘re-nig’ and not ‘re-neyg,’ by native AmE speakers from the working and under classes—-white and black—-without self-consciousness or irony. As was mentioned, renig is a term used in the card game, Spades—-how ironic is that—-a favored past-time of Black prisoners in the States and without etymological relation to the hateful ol mojo of Race, see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Not that long ago I asked a question about [19th century north American slang](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214121/19th-century-american-english-slang) which contained the following

> ... Bob, be honest, never take a man's trick wot don't belong to you, nor clip cards, nor **nig**, for then you can't look your man in the face, and when that's the case there's no fun in the game...

The excerpt is dated 1858, and none of the users who posted answers suggested that the expression ***nig*** was racist, nor a back formation of the term *nigger*; in fact there is not a single comment in the entire page that implies otherwise. Obviously in the OP's question the term *nig* is used in a derisive, and highly racist fashion but the origins of *nig* is far older than the OP's question and answer might suggest.

Robusto posted [the following comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214121/19th-century-american-english-slang#comment455030_214134) explaining the possible meaning of the term used in that context, which I reproduce verbatim

> Also, I believe *nig* is a shortening of the word *renege*, which means to trump a card instead of following suit when you still have a card of the led suit in your hand. For example, if someone led hearts and you had a heart you would be required to play a heart. If you trumped the trick instead (which is permissible only if you are out of the led suit), and were later caught at the subterfuge, you would be said to have *reneged*. Saying "don't nig" is another way of saying "don't cheat." –  Robusto Dec 11 '14 at 13:06

From [The Century Dictionary](http://www.global-language.com/CENTURY/) online (courtesy of [Eric Kowall](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/214123/44619)) the verb **nig** is defined

> **nig** (nig), *v. i.* nig to be stingy; be niggardly. "It is better to healpe the mother and mistresss of thy country with thy goods and body than by witholding thy handle, and *nigging*, to make her not hable to kepe out thine ennemy?" <sub>Alymer (**1559**).</sub>

Comment: Your answer is etymologically interesting, Mari-Lou A, but I can't help thinking that it's beside the point in the context of the quotation that the OP cites. If we were discussing a caption that read "Honkies gonna honk," we might very well note that the verb _honk_ is unrelated to the noun _honky_. But the point of the attempted witticism in the quotation is not to bring an unrelated verb into play, it seems to me, but to repeat a truncated form of the racial slur _honky_ as a verb. That, I think, is ultimately what's going on with the caption in the OP's question as well.

Comment: @SvenYargs but the question is *What does the* **verb** *nig means?* And my answer shows that as a verb it has historical origins and negative connotations. Grammatically speaking, *nig* in "gonna nig" appears and behaves like a verb. I agree with the OP's answer but it seems several users do not, and have downvoted his answer. What could the possible motivation be then?

Comment: @SvenYargs There's a small chance that it isn't beside the point. The caption might have been a pun on the derivation from "nigger" and that from "renege" or "niggard". But I'll admit, from the amount of racism I've seen on the Internet, that the chance is slim.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - I just encountered the question, attendant controversy, and your answer and felt compelled to add an answer of my own. Hope you find this of interest.

Comment: It's a very thorough  and well-researched answer.

Answer (score 2):

**1.)** Whether "nig" is a back-formation from the well-known racist term for American Black people, or branches off from that other pejorative, “*niggardly*,” what’s plain is that the mere utterance of the word so traumatizes many of us that—-unlike any other word I know—-even the linguists of EL&U have great difficulty extricating themselves sufficiently from a past we find deeply shameful to appreciate the extraordinary evolution that this word has undergone.

**2.)** As correctly stated by the OP/Answerer/Editor(?), “*Niggers Gonna Nig*,” is a snowclone of “*Haters Gonna Hate*.” In order to snowclone the original the initial 2-syllable word “*Haters*” became “*Niggas*,” and the final single-syllable word, “*Hate*” became “*Nig*.” While some may claim that “*nig*” is a truncation of “*nigger*,” it has no currency in the US in that sense. “*Nig*,” as short for “*nigger*” is only used by *closeted* racists fearful of being overheard and thus *outed*, especially when scary Black people are within hearing range. Whereas, proud racists relish fully pronouncing the *N*-word and loudly proclaiming their vaunted ignorance a virtue before all.

**3.)** Additionally, though the text at the bottom of the picture in question reads, “*Niggers Gonna Nig*,” if you hover on that pic you’ll notice that the photo is actually tagged, “*Niggas*,” and not *Niggers*. This is not a quibbling distinction, for the two words have opposite meanings today. “*Niggers*” still means what everyone knows that it means. But, in a potent act of cultural hacking with deep political implications, while Massa slumbered serenely dreaming of empire, the black youth of America crept into his white house, stole the Massa’s forked-tongue, and liberated themselves from the hateful label that had shackled and diminished them for the last 500 years.

**4.)** Initially this hijacked term was reserved for Blacks. But words that truly resonate (for good *or* ill) always gain wide currency, and so over time the term came to be applied to any *non*-Caucasian peoples. As employed by the most progressive of today’s youth, however, “*Nigga*” or “*Niggas*,” is a term without racial bearing in many (not all) situations, applied to any person who is a victim of prejudice similar to that suffered by Blacks; to any person who is economically, politically, or socially disenfranchised. In other words, in the most *liberal* sense, “*nigga*” now means “*true* or *real* human; *just plain folk*; *comrade*; and even more which I don’t care to document right now. Wikipedia [check-it-out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigga) gets pretty close but doesn’t go quite far enough.

**5.)** The graphic media that gave rise to this controversy was created by Sean C., an  American Black from NYC with the brand, "*Satisfies69*". Sean C. acts as an *agent provocateur* who specializes in multimedia “shock-art” that is deliberately as iconoclastic as possible—-mocking all aspects of modern culture’s double-standards, violating all its taboos, and holding the funhouse mirror (as it were) up to society’s shadow-face. While at first blush *Satisfies69*’s work may strike one as the First Amendment’s worst nightmare, and merely vulgar or pornographic (and much of it is!), I find it highly doubtful the work is intended to be racist. Much of his work (I believe) is also socially and politically relevant and  meant to deflate our pretensions and exorcize our "badder" devils.

**6.)** Contrary to the commentary, “*Renig*,” *is* pronounced ‘re-*nig*’ and *not* ‘re-*neyg*,’ by native AmE speakers *from the working and under classes*—-White *and* Black—-without self-consciousness *or* irony. As was mentioned, *renig* is a term used in the card game, *Spades*—-how ironic is that—-a favored past-time of the millions of White *and* Black inmates warehoused in the *gulags* of the United States, and again, is without etymological relation to that hateful ol' racial mojo.

Comment: @tepples - sorry I'm so late with this but I just encountered the question (and attendant controversy) and felt compelled to respond. Hope you find this edifying.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Though I encountered this question too late (the OP had already accepted an answer), because I was neither satisfied with the premises of the question itself or any of the answers--some of which were just erroneous, while others were only partially correct--I felt compelled to add one of my own. I'm not soliciting votes, FF, but thought you might find my answer of interest. –  Little Eva 36 mins ago   edit

Answer (score 1):

It should take all of five minutes of using Google to figure out.
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Big%20Nig

Although it's not really pejorative, I can totally understand why someone would take offense to the term.  I can also totally understand why they wouldn't, with similar racial slurs being echoed constantly in hardcore gangsta rap music.

Now here's some dorky kids from New Jersey playing around.
http://www.angelfire.com/ult/bignig/

In the convenience store WaWa, an iced tea tumbler was offered that gave tremendous discounts on fountain drinks when given to the clerk. Because huge dudes involved in construction who "happen to be black" (thanks George Carlin!) would fill the damn things with a half gallon of "sweet tea," they became known in youth-slang as "big nigs."

Now whenever you see a kid rockin' a super big gulp you might remember the aforementioned internet meme.